# How to close dialog and open timeout dialog react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am opening a modal dialog showFeeLoading initially. If showFeeLoading is open, then in 90 seconds
showFeeLoading dialog will close, showFeeTimeout modal will open.

How to do if else conditions in useeffect?

1. showFeeTimeout modal will only open if showFeeLoading dialog is open.
2. showFeeTimeout modal will not open if showAcceptModal dialog is open

Thanks

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";

  const [{ showFeeLoading }, setFeeLoading] = useState(false);

  const [{showAcceptModal}, setAcceptModal] = useState(initialStateSetup);

  const [{ showFeeimeout }, setFeeTimeout] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {

        const timer = setTimeout(() => {

            setFeeLoading((prevState) => ({

                ...prevState,

                showFeeLoading: false,

            }));

 

            setAcceptModal((prevState) => ({

                ...prevState,

                showAcceptModal: false,

            }));

 

            //show time out screen

            setFeeTimeout((prevState) => ({

                ...prevState,

                showFeeTimeout: true,

            }));

        }, 90000);

        return () => clearTimeout(timer);

   }, []);


  const sendToFee = async () => {

    setFee((prevState) => ({

      ...prevState,

      showFeeLoading: true,

    })); 

}

 

const initialStateSetup = {

  showFee: false,
  showAcceptModal: false,
showFeeLoading: false,
showFeeTimeout:false
};

const test = (props) => {

calling sendtofee() from here 

  return (

<div></div>

  )
};
```

Comment: Please help. How to do this. If showFeeLoading dialog is open. As soon as showFeeLoading will open, Timer will start and after 90 seconds, showFeeLoading dialog will close, showFeeTimeout dialog will open. Thanks